# How to retain user generated data on form

Tags: php, class, oop

Hello guys I'm new to OOP PHP and I want to imitate the retaining of user generate data in form from procedural

here is my code:

```
<?php
```

class View_LType extends Config{

```
public function view_ltype(){
    $con = $this->con();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_leave_type`";
    $data = $con->prepare($sql);
    $data->execute();
    $result = $data->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $data){
        echo "
        <tr class='table-head'>
            <td class='numbers'>$data[leave_id]</td>
            <td>$data[leave_code]</td>
            <td>$data[leave_name]</td>
            <td class='small'>$data[leave_description]</td>
            <td><a href='#'></a></td>
        </tr>";
    }

}
public function select_ltype(){
    $con = $this->con();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_leave_type`";
    $data = $con->prepare($sql);
    $data->execute();
    $result = $data->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $data){
        echo '<option value="' . $data['leave_name'] . '">' . $data['leave_name'] . '</option>';

    
    }

}
```

}

html page:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ltype">Leave Type</label>
                    <select name="ltype" id="ltype" name="ltype" required >
                        <option>Select leave...</option>
                        <?php $view_leave->select_ltype(); ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

$data[leave_name] is what the user will select what I want is to echo selected when the user select its prefered leave name. please help me guys

Comment: `echo '<option value="' . $data['leave_name'] . '" selected>' . $data['leave_name'] . '</option>';`

Comment: thanks for the help but i need condition that if the user selected data from the options it will retain the user generated data the $data['leave_name'] is from the database it is not only 1 data there are 3 options there

Comment: Where is your code that generates all the options? We can't help you if we don't see your code.

Comment: sorry sir let me edit the post

Comment: Where is your `<select>` field?

Comment: I instantiate the function inside the class in side the select element sir

Comment: `<select name="ltype" id="ltype" name="ltype" required >` is invalid. You have `name="ltype"` twice.

Comment: I edited it out already sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the current `$data['leave_name']` is the same as the submitted "ltype", then select that option:

```
echo '<option value="' . $data['leave_name'] . '"' . (($data['leave_name'] == $_REQUEST['ltype']) ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $data['leave_name'] . '</option>';
```